# When I assigning the float value to text box, it takes round figure value

Tags: .net

```
Float a =2.48;
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
```

It display the value in text box is 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
float a = 2.48F;
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Float a =(float)2.48;
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
Try this

Comment: capital F ,(Float)